# Kubernetes best practice to access an Internal DB Service from other pods

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I have a Postgresql Service DB deployed on my cluster.
And I also have a pod, based on python that queries this DB every period of time with a random query.

Right now, I just hardcode the internal IP of the Postgresql Service within that Pod in my Python script that is auto-generated by the K8.

So currently, I have only one such pod (as I described below) but I plan to have pods with different actions, and I also have a Django that depends on this Postgresql DB.

What is the best practice to access this DB from different K8 Objects? I don't find it cleanest solution at all.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Kubernetes `Service` abstracts away pods details and internals. There are different ways to do this depending on your scenario:

1. **DB is deployed inside Kubernetes**

   You can directly refer to the service by using `service-name.namespace` notation. You can omit `namespace` if both app and db are deployed in the same namespace but you probably would want them in separate namespaces.

   Refer to https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#discovering-services.
2. **DB is external to Kubernetes (i.e. AWS RDS)**

   You can use an `ExternalName` service to abstract the endpoint of your database. This is useful for accessing your database from within your Kubernetes cluster as well as outside your cluster. For example, you can create an `Ingress` with a host `db.app.com` that points to an `ExternalName` service and make your ingress available for your entire network.

   Refer to https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname.

Comment: Thanks for the effort to answer. My scenario is DB is deployed inside Kubernetes.
But, what will I gain by separating my Django pods from the DB service?

Comment: It depends on how you would like to organize your environment. For example, if you are going with microservices, you can deploy the database along with application pods in the same namespace and restrict namespace access to the service team/owners. However, if you want to separate app and db access for whatever reason (i.e. you have different teams maintaining each) then separate namespaces would serve you well. Generally speaking, separation of concerns.

Answer (score 3):

When you expose a postgres pod via [Kubernetes service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) kubernetes will automatically create a DNS hostname in a form `<servicename>.<namespacename>.svc.cluster.local`

Store the DNS hostname of the service `postgres.default.svc.cluster.local`(this is an example, if you created the postgres service in other namespace then use that namespace in place of `default`) in a [configMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#motivation)

```
kubectl create configmap postgres-config --from-literal=POSTGRES=postgres.default.svc.cluster.local
```

And then inject it in other pod as environment variable.

```
env:
- name: POSTGRES
  valueFrom:
    configMapKeyRef:
      name: postgres-config
      key: POSTGRES
```

This way you don't have to change anything in other apps if postgres pod's IP changes for reasons like pod restart.

If for some reason the servicename changes you just change it in one place which is the configmap instead of changing it in all thousands of pods environment variable. Also in a real scenario you will have prod and non prod database. In that case you create different configMap per environment (dev, uat , prod etc)and use that environment specific configMap when deploying the pod in that specific environment.

This is the best practice and recommended approach to access a DB from different Kubernetes objects.

In addition to above since you are planning to deploy and manage postgres on kubernetes I suggest you check the [postgres operator](https://github.com/zalando/postgres-operator). This will simplify the day two operations aspect of managing a stateful workload such as postgres on kubernetes.

Comment: Why are you using a configmap? The service is perfectly discoverable using the convention you mentioned (i.e. `service-name.namespace`) without deploying a configmap.

Comment: Updated answer with explanation

Comment: I understand your argument. In my opinion, it is better to design an abstract service that is unlikely to change (i.e. `master-db.default`) instead of mapping a configmap to every pod for further abstraction. I could counter argue this: what if the configmap name changes? don't you have to update thousands of pods too?

Comment: Can you provide a reference where this is considered a best practice? I'm intrigued.

Comment: @AzizAlfoudari https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#motivation